# Setup two different from_email in FOS_USER configuration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using symfony 2.3 version and I want to configure two different from_email in fos_user configuration how is it possible and where to set my configuration.

I want to send welcome email after registration normal user using **normaluser@gmail.com** and send addition user  welcome email using **additionaluser@gmail.com**

Plz suggest any solution.

Comment: what is 'normal user' and what is 'additional user' ?

Comment: Different between two user is  additional user is access some more feature compare to normal user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by [Using A Custom Mailer.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html#using-a-custom-mailer)

Create a custom service

Example:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Mailer;
// implement all the needed methods
class CustomMailer implements MailerInterface
{
    public function sendConfirmationEmailMessage(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $template = $this->parameters['confirmation.template'];
        $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_confirm', array('token' => $user->getConfirmationToken()), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
        $rendered = $this->templating->render($template, array(
            'user' => $user,
            'confirmationUrl' => $url,
        ));

        // implement the logic that decides which from_email to use
        // change the from_email accordingly

        $this->sendEmailMessage($rendered, $this->parameters['from_email']['confirmation'], (string) $user->getEmail());
    }

}
```

and update the fos_user configuration to use your custom mailer

```
fos_user:
    # ...
    service:
        mailer: app.custom_fos_user_mailer
```

Reference links:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html#using-a-custom-mailer
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Mailer/Mailer.php

Comment: Thanks for reply. Where to create CustomMailer service class ??